# How to shift the center of the function cos(2*pi*x)*sin(pi*y) from (0.5,0.5) to (0,0) without changing the contour?

Tags: python, numpy

How to shift the center of the function `cos(2*pi*x)*sin(pi*y)` from `(0.5,0.5)` to `(0,0)` without changing the contour?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
deltaX = 0.01
deltaY = 0.01 
x = np.arange(0,1,deltaX)
y = np.arange(0,1,deltaY)
X, Y= np.meshgrid(x,y)
u = np.cos(2*pi*X)*np.sin(pi*Y)
h = plt.contourf(x,y,u)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shift the range:

```
x = np.arange(-.5, .5, deltaX)
y = np.arange(-.5, .5, deltaY)
```

or if you don't want the picture to change (although the contour won't be correct)

```
h = plt.contourf(x - .5, y - .5, u)
```

Comment: With `u = np.cos(2*np.pi*(X+0.5))*np.sin(np.pi*(Y+0.5))`, you mean?

Comment: shifting the range changes the contour.

Comment: @bharat yes, functions generally have different output with different inputs.